# How to open the same running Activity as a new one?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity that used to launch another one according to a button pressed, the new one will be either a whole new one or as like the currently running one, So, when launching a new one I'm getting the creation animation as the following:

[image]

but when launching the same Activity I got one of two behaviors:

**1-** when launching it vie `recreate()` the activity just blinks to change the statistics.(which is pretty normal to have)

**2-** when dealing with it as if it's another activity by using `intent()` with `CLEAR_TOP` flag I got the following :

- ways I already used:

  ```
  Intent intent;

  // 1 (dealing with it as a whole new one by passing the Activity Class)

      intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                                          MyActivity.class);
                                  intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
                                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                  startActivity(intent);
                                  finish();

  // 2 (just getting the current one directly)

      intent = getIntent();
                      finish();
                      startActivity(intent);
  ```

  - result for the two ways :

[image]

So, how to open the same Opened Activity with the animation of opening a new one?(i.e. like in the first pic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution by using `CLEAR_TASK` **intent flag** which according to [that link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) `will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started.`

So, it will be the following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        MyActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // Here We Are
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```